# Twig write from Yaml file

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

I have this problem: 
My yaml file:

```
locale: en 
 codes:
    button.cancel: Cancel
    button.accept: Accept
    radio.male: Male
    radio.female: Female
```

I need to write all of yaml file into my page

controller action:

```
/**
     * @Route("/read/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function readAction()
    {
        $yaml = new Parser();
        $file = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents(getcwd() .'/file.yml'));
        return $this->render('AnyoneYamlGeneratorBundle:GenerateController:read.html.twig', array(
            'files' => $file,
            ));
    }
```

my twig file:

```
{% for file in files %}
{% for key,value in file  %}
{{key}}: {{value}}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

answer of my browser is

```
button.cancel: Cancel
button.accept: Accept
radio.male: Male
radio.female: Female
```

and i need all of my yaml file
Thanks for help

Comment: *i need all of my yaml file* I see that all the content of the file is already displayed. What is the problem?

Comment: missing locale: en 
 en:

Comment: There is no `key,value` for `locale` since it's not an array. I think that's why it's not displayed.

Comment: solved answer is down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK i solved this is twig file:

```
locale: {{files["locale"]}}<br>
codes:<br>
 {% for file in files %}
  {% for code,value in file  %}
  &nbsp;{{code}}: {{value}}<br>
  {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```